# System.Text.Json Custom JsonConverter<DateTime> .Read() method not being used by .Deserialize()

Tags: c#, json, .net-core, system.text.json

I'm having trouble with the System.Text.Json and custom datetime formats.

I have created a custom converter and it was working in my api project.
When i build my client i tried using the same class, but the .Deserialize() methods won't call .Read() on the DateTime property of my class.

Anyone experienced the same issue?

```
public class DateTimeConverter : JsonConverter<DateTime>
{
    private static readonly string _format = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.fff";

    public override DateTime Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        return DateTime.ParseExact(reader.GetString(), _format, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, DateTime value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    => writer.WriteStringValue(value.ToUniversalTime().ToString(_format));
}

public async Task<StockUnitInfo> GetStockUnitInfoAsync(Inbound inbound, CancellationToken token = default)
{
    var uri = Uri.EscapeUriString($"{_httpClient.BaseAddress}/Readers/{inbound.Position}/StockUnits/{inbound.Barcode}");

    var test = await _httpClient.GetStringAsync(uri);

    var response = await _httpClient.GetStreamAsync(uri);

    var _serializationOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions
    {
        Converters = { new DateTimeConverter() }
    };

    return await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<StockUnitInfo>(response, _serializationOptions, token);
}

public class StockUnitInfo
{
    public string barcode { get; set; }
    public string wms_batch_id { get; set; }
    public string gtin { get; set; }

    //[JsonConverter(typeof(DateTimeConverter))]
    public DateTime sort_date { get; set; }
    public string talleys_batch_number { get; set; }
    public int expected_batch_size { get; set; }
    public string destination { get; set; }
    public bool fast_mover { get; set; }
    public int stackable { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
}
```

Minimal reproducible example as requested:

```
using System;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

class Program
{
    public class DateTimeConverter : JsonConverter<DateTime>
    {
        //private static readonly string _format = "yyyy.MM.dd'T'HH:mm:ss.fff'Z'";  //formato api?
        private static readonly string _format = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.fff";


        public override DateTime Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
        {
            return DateTime.ParseExact(reader.GetString(), _format, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }

        public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, DateTime value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
        => writer.WriteStringValue(value.ToUniversalTime().ToString(_format));
    }
    public class StockUnitInfo
    {
        public string barcode { get; set; }
        public string wms_batch_id { get; set; }
        public string gtin { get; set; }

        //[JsonConverter(typeof(DateTimeConverter))]
        public DateTime sort_date { get; set; }
        public string talleys_batch_number { get; set; }
        public int expected_batch_size { get; set; }
        public string destination { get; set; }
        public bool fast_mover { get; set; }
        public int stackable { get; set; }
        public string message { get; set; }
    }
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string json = "{\"barcode\":\"201930823\",\"wmsBatchId\":\"c3e4d921-8779-46f7-ac28-b1f523845329\",\"gtin\":\"01080\",\"sortDate\":\"2019-09-20T11:59:59.999\",\"talleysBatchNumber\":\"STK0233\",\"expectedBatchSize\":1,\"destination\":\"5A05\",\"fastMover\":false,\"stackable\":0,\"message\":\"Pallet directed to CS4\"}";

        var _serializationOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions
        {
            Converters = { new DateTimeConverter() }
        };
        var result = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<StockUnitInfo>(json, _serializationOptions);

        Console.WriteLine(result.sort_date);
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the Json that does not deserialize?

Comment: .. or (better) prepare [mcve] with input what demonstrates the issue. During preparing you may solve problem youself btw.

Comment: thank you for your suggestions, is it more clear now?

Comment: @stuartd Is the sample sufficient?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason for this is that the name of the class property and the name of the Json property are different:

> `"sortDate": "2019-09-20T11:59:59.999"`

And

> `public DateTime sort_date { get; set; }`

In order to deserialize that json, you need to either make the names the same, or tell the serializer what to do by adding an attribute to tell what the equivalent name is:

```cs
// For NewtonSoft.Json
// [JsonProperty("sortDate")]

// For System.Text.Json
[JsonPropertyName("sortDate")]
public DateTime sort_date { get; set; }
```

Once that is added your sample code runs correctly:

[image]

Comment: Other than adding the `JsonPropertyName` attribute, you could also consider implementing your own `JsonNamingPolicy` to support snake_case and set that as the `PropertyNamingPolicy` in the `JsonSerializerOptions` or wait for the `SnakeCase` support to get added to the framework: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/782

Comment: oh god, how did i not see that